# How to form select * from query in salesforce by using scala+spark connector?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, salesforce

This is working:

```
val soql = "select id, name, amount from opportunity"   

val sfDF  = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce")
         .option("username", "*******")
         .option("password", "***********")
         .option("soql", soql)
         .option("version", "37.0")
         .load()
```

But I am forming `select * from opportunity` it is not working, throwing an malformed query error exception.

i am getting below exception:

18/02/23 11:56:40 WARN ForceAPIImpl: Error while executing salesforce query
java.lang.Exception: Accessing https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/query?q=select%20*%20from%20opportunity failed. Status 400. Reason Bad Request
 Error from server [{"message":"\nselect * from opportunity\n      ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:7\nunexpected token: '*'","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]
        at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.execute(HTTPHelper.java:102)
        at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.get(HTTPHelper.java:75)
        at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.get(HTTPHelper.java:79)

Comment: can should share the exception error message please ?

Comment: @eliasah please find the below error:  18/02/23 11:56:40 WARN ForceAPIImpl: Error while executing salesforce query
java.lang.Exception: Accessing https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/query?q=select%20*%20from%20opportunity failed. Status 400. Reason Bad Request
 Error from server [{"message":"\nselect * from opportunity\n      ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:7\nunexpected token: '*'","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]
        at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.execute(HTTPHelper.java:102)
        at com.springml.salesforce.wave.util.HTTPHelper.get(HTTPHelper.java:75)

Comment: can you update your question instead of adding info in comments ? also can you write the whole code that is failing ? Obfuscate passwords and username, db address of course

Comment: escape your `*` in ur query, clearly says `unexpected token *`

Comment: if we remove * also same error it's throwing @SajanChandran

Comment: I removed my answer. You are wasting my time and doing no efforts with your question.

Comment: Sorry @eliasah what i am expected how to resolve this problem.thanks for spending valuable time

Comment: @eliash i am not using spark alone here.  I am trying salesforce with spark here for which your solution will not work thats what i was trying to explain. I think you took it in wrong.. thanks for help ... i am trying different things not wasting any one efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enter code here:val config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(username);
config.setPassword(password);
val authEndpoint = ("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0");
config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndpoint);
config.setServiceEndpoint(authEndpoint);
val conn = new PartnerConnection(config);    
    var connection = conn.describeGlobal()
    // Get the sObjects from the describe global result
    val sobjectResults = connection.getSobjects()
   var res=conn.describeSObject("Opportunity")
   var fields = res.getFields().toBuffer;
   println("Has " + fields.length + " fields");
   var strFields=""
   // Iterate through each field and gets its properties       
  // fields.foreach{x=> //println("filed name is"+x.getLabel);println("filed name is "+x.getName())}

  fields.foreach{x=> //println("filed name is "+x.getName())
     if(x == null || x == "" || x==" ")
     {
       strFields = x.getName;
       }else{
         strFields = strFields + "," + x.getName;}
```

}

var qry = "select " + strFields.toString.replaceFirst(",", "") + " from Opportunity";
println("query is::::::::::"+qry);

var sfDF=Spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce").option("username", username).option("password", password).option("soql", qry).load()

Comment: my question has -2 points why? and I am posting my answer also.

Answer (score 1):

SOQL does not support `select *` you must specify which fields to select. If you want to dynamically build the equivalent of select * you can use the describeSObject API call to determine all the field names, and build a query from that.

Comment: DescribeSObjectResult = connection.describeSObject(string sObjectType);  Here connection in sence what?  and 8.0 End Point

https://na2-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/8.0
7.0 End Point

https://na2-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/7.0 links also not working. @superfell explain me and how to create decribeobject by using connection in spark+scala

Comment: I got solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation:

```
import com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeSObjectResult;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.Field;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class SfdcGetColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        String endpoint = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0";

        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.setAuthEndpoint(endpoint);
        config.setServiceEndpoint(endpoint);
        PartnerConnection conn = new PartnerConnection(config);    

        // Get the sObjects from the describe global result
        DescribeSObjectResult res = conn.describeSObject(args[0]);      
        Field[] fields = res.getFields();
        System.out.println("=======Has " + fields.length + " fields");
        System.out.println("==========FIELDS========");

        for(int i=0; i<fields.length; i++)
        {
            String strFieldNm = fields[i].getName();
            System.out.print(strFieldNm+",");
        }

    }

}
```

POM.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.springml</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-salesforce_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You need to run this as `spark-submit` in `--deploy-mode client`